# CakePHP3 query object returns wrong datatype

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Query object return avg rating is 3 instead of 3.5, when I have 4 and 3 values for ratings in the table

```
        $query = $Comments->find()
            ->select(['rating'=>'AVG(rating)'])
            ->first();
```

Comment: Clear the DB cache "\tmp\cache\models", then recheck

Comment: This has been answered [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/16234). Please try to avoid crossposting, but when you do, post the answer so that people don't waste their time trying to solve your problem - thanks!